# How to characterize the dimension of a manifold using homology?

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, dimension-theory-analysis

This might be a trivial question but I'm a physicist, not a mathematician. For me, the n dimensional euclidean space is n dimensional as a vector space. I have heard however that there more intrinsic characterization of the number of dimensions (of vector space or manifolds) using homology?
I'm looking at least for some keywords so that I can dig the web.
Thank you!

Comment: What one finds is that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open subset and $x \in U$ then $H_i(U, U - \{x\}) \simeq \tilde{H}_{i-1}(U - \{x\}) \simeq \tilde{H}_{i-1}(S^{n-1})$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $i = n$ and $0$ otherwise. But maybe I'm using too much here (relative homology, excision).